# Selection in a ComboBoxEditor change the row selected in DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, advanceddatagrid, itemeditor

### Here is a good problem :

I've got an AdvancedDatagrid with Combobox as ItemEditor (until there, no problems ...).
This ComboBoxEditor get this behavior : **selection = close editor**

### BUT

when I click on a value in the ComboBox, it selecte it and close as wished, but the click also put the selection in the row of the datagrid below, and then open the editor of this row.

This comportment appear only with *Internet Explorer* (8 & 9)

Any idea why it's like this with IE, and more important, how to workaround this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: For now, I've found one workaround, but I find it very bad :'( => I use setInterval at the close of the Editor (EditorEnd) and put a flag to false, then wait (~1000 millis) to put the flag back to true. With that, I do a test at the oppening of the Editor (Beginning and Begin) over this flag.

Comment: It might help if you post some code - that might get you help faster